# GLib testing framework detects only one test when it should detect several

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing, glib

I have a small test program that run several test, however the test report tells me that there is only one test passed.

## The code

```c
static void test_foo(void) {
  g_assert(TRUE);
}
static void test_bar(void) {
  g_assert(TRUE);
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  g_test_init (&argc, &argv, NULL);

  g_test_add_func ("/foo/foo", test_foo);
  g_test_add_func ("/foo/bar", test_bar);

  return g_test_run ();
}
```

## The result

```
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for foobar x.x.x
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 1
# PASS:  1
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  0
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
```

Does it skip some test ? How to fix it ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Automake testing framework is detecting one test *program*, which contains two GLib *tests*. To see the results of the two tests, look at the `.log` file corresponding to your test executable.

If you write a custom test driver to get Automake to recognize each test separately, let me know -- I'm interested!